# How to get __debugInfo to work with XDebug?

Tags: php, xdebug, php-5.6

It seems `__debugInfo` does not work when xdebug overwrites `var_dump`.

Is there anyway to make this work?

I am using PHP 5.6.0 and XDebug 2.2.5

Comment: I suppose you could make a wrapper that calls it directly... or moan at Derick so he'll fix XDebug.

Comment: Yes - please file a bug report at http://bugs.xdebug.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed in Xdebug - soon to be released: https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/commit/14159486d8d77732b5ae193ca9431bae80c94074

Comment: Since broken again and resolved as wontfix https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1777

Comment: Since fixed again https://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00002041 :)